# Convert A Android Design (Gingerbread) to Material Design

Tags: java, android

At first this is my First Post So If im wrong please understand it thanks.
Now my Problem: I have an forum which is Vbulletin well I bought mobile Suite also with it. The Android App Is really outdated with the Design it still have Gingerbread Style -_-. I decompiled the APK i have The Classes Java Source Code and Also the XML Files. Can somebody help me how to restyle the App

Thanks :D

The Styles.xml Looks Like This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="com_facebook_loginview_default_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/com_facebook_loginview_text_color</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/com_facebook_loginbutton_blue</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_padding_left</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_height</item>
        <item name="android:width">@dimen/com_facebook_loginview_width</item>
    </style>
    <style name="com_facebook_loginview_silver_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">18.0sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff4b5164</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/com_facebook_loginbutton_silver</item>
        <item name="android:height">44.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:width">205.0dip</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Animations" />
    <style name="Animations.GrowFromBottom" parent="@style/Animations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_top</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Animations.PopDownMenu" parent="@style/Animations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/grow_from_topright_to_bottomleft</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/shrink_from_bottomleft_to_topright</item>
    </style>
    <style name="menu_dialog_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/menu_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Edit here also The manufest File :D

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.vbulletin.build_3120">
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".App">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.Register"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.Home"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ActivityStream" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogsTab"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.PrivateMessagesTab"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.NotificationsListActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogEntriesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.PrivateMessagesInboxEntriesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogCategoriesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.PrivateMessagesFoldersList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumsMainList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumsThreadList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumPostsList" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumPostActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.TestActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.MyProfileTab"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ProfileTab"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.FriendListActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.NotYetImplemented"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.SearchThreadList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.SearchPostList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumPublishFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.PrivateMessageFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.SubscribedListActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ForumSimpleSelectListActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogCommentList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.PrivateMessageActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogPublishFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogPublishOptionsActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.BlogEditEntryFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CommentPublishFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CommentActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.SearchBlogList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AlbumListActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.NewAlbumFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AlbumActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AlbumSlideShowActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.GlobalSearchOptionsActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AlbumPictureCommentList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.GlobalSearchResultsActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AlbumUploadPictureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ProfileUploadPictureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.FullScreenPictureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsTab"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsEntriesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsCategoriesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsSectionList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsPublishFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsCommentList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.CmsPublishOptionsActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.SearchCmsList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.VisitorMessagePublishFormActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ProfileAboutList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ProfileVisitorMessagesList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.ProfileFriendsList"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.EditProfileActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.Demo"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.AttachVideoActivity"/>
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.vbulletin.activity.RequestTokenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:host="callback" android:scheme="x-oauthflow"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/>
        <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.mdotm.android.view.MdotMActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMBrowserActivity"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer"/>
        <service android:name="com.vbulletin.services.YoutubeUploadService"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Hmmm the Styles.xml Looks Like this O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Theme.AppCompat` in your `styles.xml` file. For example something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Don't give up, go for it! ;)

Comment: I just added The Styles.xml Well how now?

Comment: In your AndroidManifest.xml inside of application tag put these line: android:theme="@style/YourTheme" (YourTheme should be defined in styles.xml, see above). Your theme should be then set up for whole application. If you want to use it for particular Activity, put it inside of activity tag.

Comment: So you mean I have to Delet the whole styles.xml and put the code Above? (Sorry for Noob questions)

Comment: I just Attached the AndroidManifest.xml